# Using regex two find two patterns at once in python

Tags: python

I dont know whether it is possible to achieve what I am looking for. I am trying to use regex to match two patterns at same time. So here is what I am trying to do.

```
for i in j: # Does something and gives me an output
   m = re.search('uni\/tn-(.*)\/aa\/cc-(.*)') 
   if m:
       name = m.group(1) # gives me everything i require, but misses one output whose pattern is bit different from what i am using in regex

   second pattern = ('uni\/tn-(.*)\/yy-(.*)/zz-(.*)/aa/cc-(.*)')
```

One thing I find in common in the both the patterns is "uni/tn-(.*)". If I use this generic regex pattern, it is not yielding anything.

Apologies in advance if it is something that is not doable. Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` in a regexp.

Comment: Anything that's matched by the second pattern will also be matched by the first pattern, since the `yy` and `zz` parts will be matched by `.*` in the pattern.

Comment: `re.search('uni/tn-(.*)/(?:yy-(.*)/zz-(.*)/)?aa/cc-(.*)')`  ?